# Google Actions / Dialogflow - open installed application

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a Google Actions application connected to Dialogflow and Firebase. Is there any way to open another Java application (installed on device - for ex. Android) from the Dialogflow? I was hoping that deep-link 'native-android-application' would be way to go, but I was not able to find anything.

To summarise I'm thinking about following flow:

1. Talk to 'app ABC' (Google assistant will initialise the google actions app)
2. Send 1 (Send function in 'app ABC' will be invoked)
3. 'app ABC' will return a **deep-link** to the native android application 'native-android-application' (native-android-application://info?id=')
4. When user clicks on the returned response the native-android-application will be opened

Comment: What do you mean "I was not able to find anything"?

Comment: Anything useful, that is why I ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still in developer preview (so you can test it, but can't yet publish it publicly), but you can use the [Android Link helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#android_link) that is part of the Actions on Google API. You need to link the app in the Actions developer console and then you'll be able to something like this:

```
function androidLink (app) {
  app.askToDeepLink('Great! Looks like we can do that in the Android app.', 'Gizmos for Android',
    'example://gizmos', 'com.example.gizmos', 'handle this for you');

  // Results in prompt:
  // "Great! Looks like we can do that in the Android app."
  // "Can I send you to Gizmos for Android mobile app to handle this for you?"
}
```