# how can I deeplink an app from Google Assistant?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, deep-linking, google-assistant-sdk

I'm creating a dialogflow agent integrated with Google Assistant.
What I'd like to do is to open an app (my app) when a proper intent is matched. I've seen that actions like Youtube, Spotify etc. are able to do that, for example I can tell the Youtube action "search for cats video" and the Youtube app will open with a list of cats videos.
I tried to use the DeepLink class but I then noticed it's deprecated.
[DeepLink class](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/2.10.0/classes/_service_actionssdk_conversation_helper_deeplink_.deeplink.html)
Is there any way you can suggest me to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview). Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Find the right [built-in intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents). `actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE` should be the right one for you.
2. [Create and update actions.xml](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/action-schema). It should look like

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This is a sample actions.xml -->
    <actions>
        <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <!-- Use url from inventory match for deep link fulfillment -->
            <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />
            <!-- Define parameters with inventories here -->
            <parameter name="feature">
                <entity-set-reference entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet" />
            </parameter>
        </action>
        <entity-set entitySetId="featureParamEntitySet">
            <!-- Provide a URL per entity -->
            <entity url="myapp://deeplink/one" name="featureParam_one" alternateName="@array/featureParam_one_synonyms" />
            <entity url="myapp://deeplink/two" name="featureParam_two" alternateName="@array/featureParam_two_synonyms" />
        </entity-set>
    </actions>
   ```

Comment: Hi Vijay, yeah I was aware of the existence of App Actions but I'm not sure it is the solution for what I need. Basically I'm developing a conversational action for Google Assistant and in the middle of the conversation, if the user ask to, I'd like to show some data in my app instead of showing it directly on the Assistant screen. So my question is: how can I connect the conversational action with the app?

Comment: Are you sure you set the right url for the post? I cannot see it

Comment: My apologies, wrong link, here the comment with the right link:"Could you please take a look in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49817809/10409068), they mentioned a workaround winch consist into use the [Android Link helper](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/helpers#android_link) that is part of the Actions on Google API –"